# How can Rpi connect a GPS module?

Tags: serial, gps

I've tried reconnecting an old GPS module to the UART pins on my raspberry pi, but it seems it's not able to get a satellite fix.

I've had troubles trying to get gpsd started, but I'm able to test the connection with gpsmon. It seems capable of parsing data from the serial connection, but not a single satellite is ever seen.

Then I tried looking at the raw data using the commands

> To set it to 9600 baud: *stty -F /dev/serial0 9600*
>
> To print out the data: *cat /dev/serial0*

What I got back doesn't look quite right to me. Here's an excerpt:

> [0x01][0x1B][0x0F][0x1F][0x0C] ÿÿÿÿ$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
>
> M,,M,,*7D
>
> 9,,,N*44
>
> [0x01][0x1B][0x0F][0x1F][0x0C] 
>   ÿÿÿÿ$GPRMC,054305.099,V,,,,,0.00,0.00,220519,,,N*47
>
> A^X^O^_^L ÿÿÿÿ$GPGGA,054305.099,,,,,0,00,,,M,,M,,*7F
>
> $GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32
>
> 0519,,,N*47
>
> A^X^O^_^L ÿÿÿÿ$GPGGA,054305.099,,,,,0,00,,,M,,M,,*7F
>
> $GPGGA,054306.099,,,,,0,00,,,M,,M,,*7C
>
> 9,,,N*47
>
> A^X^O^_^L ÿÿÿÿ$GPGGA,054305.099,,,,,0,00,,,M,,M,,*7F
>
> $GPGGA,054310.099,,,,,0,00,,,M,,M,,*7B

I've replaced control characters with their hex codes in [] brackets.

Is this normal, have I used incorrect settings, or does it mean the GPS module is faulty?

[EDIT]

This is the module in question:
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Using an external antenna (placed ~1m away from the pi).

[UPDATE]

Nearly 48 hours later, I have checked on things, having been left as they were when the question was first posed.
I hadn't received any fix within 3 hours which prompted me to make the post.

Sometime since, the GPS module appears to have started working as expected. 
The odd ascii/control characters are no longer present in the serial output. The GPS now has a fix, and is seeing 6 - 9 satellites.

I don't have an explanation for how it has recovered.

Perhaps it was RF noise as suggested by Dougie , but for that to be true, it would mean that the TV I was using for display output (3m away) would have been causing the interference as nothing else is nearby that has changed (powered/unpowered) over the duration. The PI's wifi has been enabled throughout. I have tried testing whether power cycling the TV has any effect on the GPS reception by monitoring the serial output and it does not look like there is any effect.

It could have been ESD suggested by Dmitry Grigoryev, although if that were true then I guess leaving the antenna charged would have caused it, which dissipated over time, leaving no lasting damage? Is this possible?

It was stored in a dry place (heated indoors), but I can't rule out moisture damage as I live in a very humid area. Could keeping it powered up, have warmed it up, leading to to evapouration, removing electrical interference?

My other conclusion is that giving it a restricted view (still a good chunk of sky - around 1/3rd), caused it to miss a lot of updates, making a cold start take much, much longer than expected? This wouldn't explain the corruption seen in the serial output though, would it?

Comment: Does the GPS unit have a clear sky view?

Comment: The NMEA sentences you're getting appear valid. There's just a lot of noise in with your signal. How is your GPS connected to your RPi, how long is the cable?

Comment: The following youtube might give you some tips -Troubleshooting the Adafruit Ultimate GPS When Not Getting a Fix 11,156 views
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtqVrwwVfGY

Comment: @joan It's located directly (in contact) with a window. It has a visibility of an estimated 33% of the sky. I've used the location before with success when the GPS module was new.

Comment: @Dougie The cable is about 10cm-15cm long, using a raspberry pi breadboard breakout.

Answer (score 3):

Those UART GPS modules often have quite poor reception, so you will only get a fix with a clear sky view. Not inside your house, not just out of the window, not on a lawn right next to your house, not under the trees. Additionally, such modules rely on the GPS signal to get the GPS constellation data, which is very slow and can take several minutes. The worst of such modules won't store the constellation data anywhere, so every time you power down the module, getting a fix will again requires up to 12.5 minutes. GPS messages are transmitted at 50 bps which takes a lot of time even though those messages are quite small.

Additionally, even if the module talks to your UART correctly, it doesn't mean it's not damaged. For example, you could have killed the amplifier with ESD by touching the antenna. If the module doesn't get a fix under a clear sky in ten minutes or so, I would bin it and get a new one.

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

> 1. Tried reconnecting GPS module to Rpi UART, not able to get a fix, ...
> 2. Trouble trying to get gpsd started, able to test the connection with gpsmon, ...
> 3. Raw data normal, GPS module fried?

***Short Answer***

---

---

### ***2020 June Update***

This answer is on the old Rpi3 and GPSD v3.16.  Please also read the following updated answer on *Rpi4B and GPSD v3.17*.

[Rpi to GPS Module QueCtel L80-R Problem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113057/gps-module-not-working/113066#113066)

---

---

> 1. Well, to get a fix, you don't need the GPS module connected to Rpi UART.  If you test with the Rpi UART disconnected from the GPS module,
>      your chance of getting a fix will be   at least 0.1% higher.
> 2. Once you have gotten a fix, the little status blue LED should start blinking slowly, around once per second.  If blue LED not
>      blinking, that mean no fix yet.
> 3. If there is no fix, you can still talk to the GPS module through UART, but a not fixed GPS module will only give you yesterday data,
>      which is still useful any way, but of course not realtime GPS data.
> 4. There are 101 reasons that you can not get a fix.  Let me list one by one.  The list of reasons is very long, so I will put it in the
>      long answer below.

*/ to continue, ...*

***Long Answer***

*/ to continue, ...*

***Research Notes***

*/ to continue, ...*

***References***

[AliEXpress GPS + Beidou Dual mode positioning module ATK1218-BD ATK-S1216 -US$24](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/GPS-Beidou-Module-de-positionnement-bimode-ATK1218-BD-ATK-S1216/32978748359.html)

[TaoBao dual GPS (GPS + BaiDu) Positioning Module ATK1218-BD ATK-S1216 - ¥98](https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?id=581979887207&spm=a1z1r.7974869.0.0.269c3ad4zWxpzT)

[Troubleshooting the Adafruit Ultimate GPS When Not Getting a Fix - Paul McWhorter 2015jun23, 11,180 views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtqVrwwVfGY)

[gpsd — a GPS service daemon](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/)

[How to read NMEA 1083 data over USB on Pi? - Rpi StackExchange 2017apr](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/65588/how-to-read-nmea-1083-data-over-usb-on-pi)

[Getting NMEA string from GPS module to your Raspberry PI B+ [duplicate] - Rpi StackExchange 2017jan](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60106/getting-nmea-string-from-gps-module-to-your-raspberry-pi-b)

[More serial ports [for GPS module]](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96697/how-many-serial-ports-are-on-the-pi-3)

[The 6 Best Arduino GPS Modules 2018](https://wiki.ezvid.com/best-arduino-gps-modules)

> SainSmart NEO-6M
>
> Hobbypower Ublox NEO-7M
>
> DIYmall G28U7FTTL
>
> Gowoops Ublox NEO-6M
>
> Readytosky Ublox NEO-M8N
>
> ***Adafruit Ultimate Breakout***

[GPSD compatible modules](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/hardware.html)

[NMEA sentences](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/NMEA.html)

[GPSD not getting a good fix-  stackOverflow 2015apr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333424/gpsd-not-getting-a-good-fix)

[Using python with a GPS receiver on a Raspberry Pi - Mark Williams 2109jan](http://ozzmaker.com/using-python-with-a-gps-receiver-on-a-raspberry-pi/)

[Adafruit Ultimate GPS HAT for Raspberry Pi A+/B+/Pi 2/Pi 3 - Mini Kit - US$45](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2324)

[AdaFruit Ultimate GPS Module Tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps)

[AdaFruit GPS HAT Tutorial PDF File](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-ultimate-gps-hat-for-raspberry-pi.pdf?timestamp=1556509130)

[AdaFruit GPS Tutorial, Schematic etc](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-hat-for-raspberry-pi/downloads)

[GlobalTop Command Set](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/PMTK_A11.pdf)

[GlobalTop GPS chip datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/GlobalTop-FGPMMOPA6H-Datasheet-V0A.pdf)

*/ to continue, ...*

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - My GPS module blinking - YouTube*

[GPS Module Blinking](https://youtu.be/1J7JlKeVxEw)

*Appendix B - My GPS module setup*

[image: GPS module setup]

*Appendix C - My GPS Antenna setup*

[image: GPS Antenna setup]

*Fix times 2019may23hkt2100 - first fix = 8 minutes, followed by 14 sec, 24 sec, 25 sec, 1.24 min, 1.13 min, then 17 min no fix, end of fixing test.*

*Appendix D - GPS Antenna Location - 4 stories down the "well"*

[image: GPS location]

*Appendix D - GPS Fix Time Measurement at Rooftop Garden*

*I am going to test if GPS fixing is possible with huge motor generated EMI around.*

[image: GPS Fixed Time Measurement at Rooftop Garden with huge EMI motor nearby]

*Appendix E - GPS Fix Time Measurement with Antenna 1 metre out of window*

I surprising found that even with the antenna just 1 meter out of the window, the fix time is regularly less than 1 minute.  My quick and dirty conclusion is that it not necessary at all to try any fix at the rooftop garden, ... :)

[image: window 1 meter GPS fix test]

*Appendix F - 200VAC in 12V AC out switching PSU  performance*

I read that the power supply for GPS module should be very stable.  So I used LiPo 11.2V power bank with heavy duty 2.5A 5V voltage regulator for testing.  This morning I used a weak 200VAC in 12V 1A PSU and light LM2596 regulator to test again.  I found fixing times very good: 1m43s, 35s, 20s, 9s, 14s.

My quick and dirty conclusion is that the PSU quality doen't mater much.  So from now on I will forget using LiPo battery bank and just use 200VAC in 12V out switching PSU.

[image: using switching psu]

*Appendix F - Downloading gpsd*

[image: gpsd download]

*Appendix G - Fix time measurements by the window L corner, 0 cm from window*

Now I am measuring fix time with antenna by the window very near to a L shape corner.  I find average fix time around 5 minutes.  So far so good.  I am using 200VAC in, 12V DC out, regulated by LM2596 regulator and found no problem.  So I will not be using any LiPo power bank in the coming tests.

[image: fix time l corner]

*Appendix H - Fix time measurement - inside L corner 50cm from window*

For antenna about 50 cm from window, first fix time decreases to 3 minutes (based on only one sample!)

*Appendix I - Hot fix time 12 metres down a concrete walled well = avg 15 seconds*

I again checked the hot fix times at the U position, 12 metres down the concrete walled well.  I very surprisingly found that the ***hot fix times*** (powering off and then on) was about ***15 seconds*** (only 4 or 5 samples)

[image: U position fix time measurements]

*Appendix J - ATK1218-BD GPS Module Specification*

[TaoBao Risym ATK1218-BD (ATK-S1216) GPS/BD dual mode GPS module - ¥98
https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?](http://id=581979887207&spm=a1z1r.7974869.0.0.269c3ad4zWxpzT)

*Features*

> 1. Chip = SkyTra S1216
> 2. Module = ATK1218-BD (former ATK-S1216)
> 3. Antenna = 3m active
> 4. Speed   = 4.8 kBaud ~ 230.4 kBaud
> 5. Protocol = NMEA-0183
> 6. Resolution = 2.5 mCEP
> 7. Refresh rate = 1/2/4/5/6/10/20 Hz (Neo-6M = 5 Hz)
> 8. Cold fix time = up to 29 seconds
> 9. Sensitivity = -165 dBm
> 10. Temperature = -40 deg C to + 85 deg C
> 11. Dimension = 25mm * 27mm
> 12. Antenna = IPX to SMA adapter
> 13. Power off hot fix (in 30 minutes) = 1 few seconds (Neo-6M = 1 ~ 5 min)
> 14. PPS status LED
> 15. Backup battery
> 16. DuPont 2.54mm male pin x 5 (STM32 Board compatible)

*Appendix K - AdaFruit Rpi GPS HAT Schematic*

[image: Adafruit Rpi GPS HAT Schematic]

*Appendix L - Testing Rpi built in UART serial loopback and repeat send char*

*The repeat send char 0x55 TxD waveform*

[image: rpi serial repeat send char 0x55]

```
# Rpi3B+ serial port loop back test v2.0 tlfong01 2019may27hkt2137 ***

# Rpi3B+ Raspbian stretch 9 (full version 2019april), IDLE python 3.5.3

# Program name = serial_loopback_2019may2702.py

# Description

# This program tests serial port loop back of
#   (1) Rpi built in UART/Serial Port, or
#   (2) USB/TTL Serial Adapter

# Rpi built in UART/Serial Port:
#   Devcie name = '/dev/serial0'
#   TxD = Rpi UART/serial port output pin = BCM GPIO pin #15  ( = Rpi 40 pin connector pin position #  8)
#   RxD = Rpi UART/serial port  input pin = BCM GPIO pin #16  ( = Rpi 40 pin connector pin position # 10)

# UART/TTL Serial Adapter/Cable ($ ls /dev/ttyUSB* to list USB/TTYserial port names)
#   Device name = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
#   Pins = Gnd, Tx, Rx, 3V3, 5V0 (3V3, 5V0 are power pins, for powering external devices) 

# Loopback hardwareware setup
#   Use a connecting wire / jumper wire / female to female DuPont connector to connect TxD pin to RxD pin

# Program execution example
# 1. Desktop GUI python 3 IDLE
#    Copy program to any directory under Rpi home directory, eg /home/python_programs  
#    File menu > save as > serial_loopback_2019may26x1.py (or Ctrl+S, or Ctrl+Shift+S)
#    Run  menu > run > run module (or F5)
# 2, Terminal mode
#    To add later

# Sample output
'''
>>> 
 RESTART: /home/pi/Python Programs/Python_Programs/test1200/serial_loopback_2019may2702.py 
        Begin serialPortLoopBack() [Remember to connect Tx to Rx!] , ...
        bytes written =  b'AT\r\n'
        bytes read    =  b'AT\r\n'
        End   serialPortLoopBack(), ...
>>> 
'''

from   time import sleep
import serial

# *** Setup serial port and set baud rate functions ***

def setSerialPortBaudRate(serialPort, baudRate):
    serialPort.baudrate = baudRate
    return

# *** Serial port write and read bytes functions ***

def serialPortWriteBytes(serialPort, writeBytes):
    serialPort.write(writeBytes)
    return

def serialPortReadBytes(serialPort, maxBytesLength):
    readBytes = serialPort.read(maxBytesLength)
    return readBytes

def serialPortWriteWaitReadBytes(serialPort, writeBytes, maxBytesLength, waitSeconds):
    serialPort.flushInput()
    serialPort.flushOutput()
    serialPort.write(writeBytes)
    sleep(waitSeconds) 
    readBytes = serialPortReadBytes(serialPort, maxBytesLength)
    print('        bytes written = ', writeBytes) 
    print('        bytes read    = ', readBytes)
    return readBytes

# *** Test functions ***

def testSerailPortRepeatWriteBytes(serialPort, writeBytes, betweenBytePauseSeconds, repeatCount):
    print('       Begin repeatWriteOneByte(), ...')   
    for i in range(repeatCount):
        serialPortWriteBytes(serialPort, writeBytes)                
        sleep(betweenBytePauseSeconds)
    print('       End   repeatWriteOneByte().')
    return

def testSerialPortLoopBack(serialPort, writeBytes, maxBytesLength, waitSeconds): 
    print('        Begin serialPortLoopBack() [Remember to connect Tx to Rx!] , ...')
    serialPortWriteWaitReadBytes(serialPort, writeBytes, maxBytesLength, waitSeconds)     
    print('        End   serialPortLoopBack(), ...')
    return

# *** Setup serial port and set baud rate ***

deviceName = '/dev/serial0' # For Rpi built UART/Serial (BCM GPIO pins 14, 15)
# deviceName = '/dev/ttyUSB0' # For USB/UART adapter/cable

serialPort0 = serial.Serial(port = deviceName,
        baudrate = 9600,
        parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout= 1)

setSerialPortBaudRate(serialPort = serialPort0, baudRate = 9600)

# *** Main Tests ***

#Test serial port repeat write bytes ***
#testSerailPortRepeatWriteBytes(serialPort = serialPort0, writeBytes = b'0x55', \
#                               betweenBytePauseSeconds = 0.005, repeatCount = 200000000)

# Test serial loop back ***
testSerialPortLoopBack(serialPort = serialPort0, writeBytes = b'AT\r\n', maxBytesLength = 32, waitSeconds = 0.01)

# End
```

*Appendix M - cgps and xgps results*

[image: cgps xgps results]

*Appendix N - Antenna in a a "well" of concrete walls*

[image: antenna in well]

*Appendix O - gpsd notes*

[GPSD Client Howto / How works - ctab](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/client-howto.html)

> While GPSD project ships several library bindings that will hide the
>   details of the wire protocol from you, you’ll understand the library
>   APIs better by knowing what a wire-protocol session looks like. After
>   reading this section, you can forget the details about commands and
>   responses and attributes as long as you hold on to the basic logical
>   flow of a session.
>
> Your client library’s open function is going to connect a socket to
>   port 2947 on the host your sensors are attached to, usually localhost.
>   On connection, the gpsd daemon will ship a banner that looks something
>   like this:
>
> {"class":"VERSION","release":"2.93","rev":"2010-03-30T12:18:17",
>   "proto_major":3,"proto_minor":2}
>
> There’s nothing mysterious here. Your server daemon is identifying
>   itself with information that may allow a client library to work around
>   bugs or potential incompatibilities produced by upgrades.
>
> To get data from the attached sensors, you need to explicitly tell the
>   daemon you want it. (Remember that it’s trying to minimize the amount
>   of time the devices are held open and in a fully powered state.) You
>   do this by issuing a WATCH command:
>
> ?WATCH={"enable":true,"json":true}
>
> This tells the daemon to watch all devices and to issue reports in
>   JSON. It can ship some other protocols as well (notably, NMEA 0183)
>   but JSON is the most capable and usually what you want.
>
> A side effect of the WATCH command is that the daemon will ship you
>   back some information on available devices.
>
> {"class":"DEVICES","devices":[{"class":"DEVICE","path":"/dev/ttyUSB0",
>   "activated":1269959537.20,"native":0,"bps":4800,"parity":"N",
>       "stopbits":1,"cycle":1.00}]}
>
> {"class":"WATCH","enable":true,"json":true,"nmea":false,"raw":0,
>   "scaled":false,"timing":false,"pps":false}
>
> The DEVICES response tells you what devices are available to the
>   daemon; this list is maintained in a way you as the application
>   designer don’t have to care about. The WATCH response will immediately
>   follow and tells you what all your watch request settings are.
>
> Up to this point, nothing has been dependent on the state of the
>   sensors. At this time, it may well be that none of those devices is
>   fully powered up yet. In fact, they won’t be, unless another
>   GPSD-enabled application is already watching when you open your
>   connection. If that’s the case, you will start seeing data
>   immediately.
>
> For now, though, let’s go back to the case where gpsd has to fire up
>   the sensors. After issuing the WATCH response, the daemon opens all of
>   them and watches for incoming packets that it can recognize. After a
>   variable delay, it will ship a notification that looks something like
>   this:
>
> {"class":"DEVICE","path":"/dev/ttyUSB0","activated":1269960793.97,
>   "driver":"SiRF binary","native":1,"bps":4800,
>       "parity":"N","stopbits":1,"cycle":1.00}
>
> This is the daemon telling you that it has recognized a SiRF binary
>   ...
>
> The GPSD daemon is designed so it doesn’t have to know anything about
>   the sensor in advance - not which of a dozen reporting protocols it
>   uses, and not even the baud rate of the serial device. The reason for
>   this agnosticism is so the daemon can adapt properly to anything a
>   hotplug event night throw at it. If you unplug your GPS while your
>   application is running, and then plug one one of a different type, the
>   daemon will cope. Your application won’t know the difference unless
>   you have told it to notice device types.
>
> You can even start your application, have it issue a WATCH, realize
>   you forgot to plug in a GPS, and do that. The hotplug event will tell
>   gpsd, which will add the new device to the watched-devices list of
>   every client that has issued a ?WATCH.
>
> In order to make this work, gpsd has a packet sniffer inside it that
>   does autobauding and packet-protocol detection. Normally the packet
>   sniffer will achieve sync in well under a second (my measured times
>   range from 0.10 to 0.53 sec at 4800bps), but it can take longer if
>   your serial traffic is degraded by dodgy cables or electrical noise,
>   or if the GPS is configured to run at an unusual speed/parity/stopbit
>   configuration.
>
> The real point here is that the delay is variable. The client library,
>   and your application, can’t assume a neat lockstep of request and
>   instant response.
>
> Once you do get your device(s) synced, things become more predictable.
>   The sensor will start shipping fix reports at a constant interval,
>   usually every second, and the daemon will massage them into JSON and
>   pass them up the client to your application.
>
> However, until the sensor achieves satellite lock, those fixes will be
>   "mode 1" - no valid data (mode 2 is a 2D fix, mode 3 is a 3D fix).
>   Here’s what that looks like:
>
> {"class":"TPV","device":"/dev/ttyUSB0", 
>   "time":"2010-04-30T11:47:43.28Z","ept":0.005,"mode":1}
>
> Occasionally you’ll get another kind of sentence, SKY, that reports a
>   satellite skyview. But TPV is the important one. Here’s what it looks
>   like when the sensor has a fix to report:
>
> {"class":"TPV","time":"2010-04-30T11:48:20.10Z","ept":0.005,
>   "lat":46.498204497,"lon":7.568061439,"alt":1327.689, epx":15.319,
>   "epy":17.054,"epv":124.484,"track":10.3797,
>   "speed":0.091,"climb":-0.085,"eps":34.11,"mode":3}
>
> Note the "mode":3 at the end. This is how you tell that the GPS is
>   reporting a full 3D fix with altitude. ...
>
> When your application shuts down, it can cancel its watch:
>
> ?WATCH={"enable":false} This will enable the daemon to close devices
>   and conserve power. Supposing you don’t do this, the daemon will time
>   out devices with no listeners, so canceling your watch is not strictly
>   necessary. But it is good manners.
>
> Another way to use the daemon is with the ?POLL command To do this,
>   issue
>
> ?WATCH={"enable":true}
>
> This activates all devices without enabling streaming of reports. You
>   can then say "?POLL;" to poll gpsd’s recorded data.
>
> ?POLL;
>
> {"class":"POLL","time":"2012-04-05T15:00:01.501Z","active":1, ...
>
> This interface is intended for use with applications like CGI scripts
>   that cannot wait on output from the daemon but must poke it into
>   responding.
>
> If you’re a clever sort, you’re already wondering what the daemon does
>   if the application at the other end of the client socket doesn’t read
>   data out of it as fast as gpsd is shipping it upwards. And the answer
>   is this: eventually the socket buffer fills up, a write from the
>   daemon throws an error, and the daemon shuts down that client socket.
>
> From the point of view of the application, it reads all the buffered
>   data and then gets a read return indicating the socket shutdown. We’ll
>   return to this in the discussion of client libraries, but the thing
>   for you to know right now is that this edge case is actually quite
>   difficult to fall afoul of. Total data volume on these sockets is not
>   high. As long as your application checks for and reads socket data no
>   less often than once a second, you won’t — and a second is a lot of
>   time in which to come back around your main loop.

Interfacing from the client side, ... / to continue, ...

Appendix P - GPS/BD Antenna positioning and 15 metre RS232 cable testing

I found that it is not necessary to place the antenna to far out of the window, 15 cm can already get a good fix.  So it is laughable that earlier I prepared a 3 meter long rod in order to position the antenna as far as possible from the window, because I read so many experience users and experts saying that PSU must be very very stable, must open sky etc etc.  All the info I read does not apply at my geographical position and GPS module.  I guess I need to check out a not GPS/BD, but GPS only, perhaps Neo-xM module to compare and contrast, to see if I still can get a good fix.

[image: fix test 15 cm]

*Appendix Q - Testing 15m and 1.5m DB9 cables to rooftop garden GPS setup*

[image: db9 cable testing]

Appendix R - GPSD Client Library for Python Programming

[GPS client library [For python programming]](https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/gpsd_json.html)

*gpsd_json — gpsd request/response protocol*

> The GPSD protocol is built on top of JSON, JavaScript Object Notation,
>   ...
>
> A request line is introduced by "?" and may include multiple commands.
>   Commands begin with a command identifier, followed either by a
>   terminating ';' or by an equal sign "=" and a JSON object treated as
>   an argument.
>
> Any ';' or newline indication (either LF or CR-LF) after the end of a
>   command is ignored. All request lines must be composed of US-ASCII
>   characters and may be no more than 80 characters in length, exclusive
>   of the trailing newline.
>
> Responses are JSON objects all of which have a "class" attribute the
>   value of which is either the name of the invoking command. There are
>   reports (including but not limited to as "TPV", "SKY", "DEVICE", and
>   "ERROR") which are not direct responses to commands.
>
> The order of JSON attributes within a response object is never
>   significant, and you may specify attributes in commands in any order.
>
> Responses never contain the special JSON value null; instead,
>   attributes with empty or undefined values are omitted. The length
>   limit for responses and reports is 1536 characters, including trailing
>   newline; longer responses will be truncated, so client code must be
>   prepared for the possibility of invalid JSON fragments.
>
> In JSON reports, if an attribute is present only if the parent
>   attribute is present or has a particular range, then the parent
>   attribute is emitted first.
>
> There is one constraint on the order in which attributes will be
>   omitted. If an optional attribute is present only when a parent
>   attribute has a specified value or range of values, the parent
>   attribute will be emitted first to make parsing easier.
>
> The next subsection section documents the core GPSD protocol.
>   Extensions are documented in the following subsections. The extensions
>   may not be supported in your gpsd instance if it has been compiled
>   with a restricted feature set.

*CORE SOCKET PROTOCOL*

Here are the core-protocol responses:

*TPV*

> A TPV object is a time-position-velocity report. The "class" and
>   "mode" fields will reliably be present. The "mode" field will be
>   emitted before optional fields that may be absent when there is no
>   fix. Error estimates will be emitted after the fix components they're
>   associated with. Others may be reported or not depending on the fix
>   quality.
>
> TPV object
>
> Name  Always? Type    Description class   Yes string  Fixed: "TPV"
>
> device    No  string  Name of originating device.
>
> status    No  numeric GPS status: %d, 2=DGPS fix, otherwise not present.
>
> mode  Yes numeric NMEA mode: %d, 0=no mode value yet seen, 1=no fix,
>   2=2D, 3=3D.
>
> time  No  string  Time/date stamp in ISO8601 format, UTC, ...
>
> alt   No  numeric Altitude in meters. Present if mode is 3.
>
> climb No  numeric Climb (positive) or sink (negative) rate, meters per
>   second.
>
> datum No  string  Current datum.
>
> lat   No  numeric Latitude in degrees: +/- signifies North/South. Present
>   when mode is 2 or 3. leapseconds  integer Current leap seconds.
>
> lon   No  numeric Longitude in degrees: +/- signifies East/West. Present
>   when mode is 2 or 3. track    No  numeric Course over ground, degrees from
>   true north.
>
> speed No  numeric Speed over ground, meters per second.
>   sep   No  numeric Estimated Spherical (3D) Position Error in meters.
>   Present if mode is 3D and DOPs can be calculated from the
>
> Example
>
> {"class":"TPV","device":"/dev/pts/1",
>       "time":"2005-06-08T10:34:48.283Z","ept":0.005,
>       "lat":46.498293369,"lon":7.567411672,"alt":1343.127,
>       "eph":36.000,"epv":32.321,
>       "track":10.3788,"speed":0.091,"climb":-0.085,"mode":3}

*SKY*

> A SKY object reports a sky view of the GPS satellite positions.
>
> Name  Always? Type    Description class   Yes string  Fixed: "SKY"
>   device    No  string  Name of originating device time No  string  Time/date
>   stamp in ISO8601 format, UTC.  satellites Yes list    List of satellite
>   objects in skyview
>
> Satellite object
>
> Name  Always? Type    Description PRN Yes numeric PRN ID of the satellite.
>   1-63 are GNSS satellites, 64-96 are GLONASS satellites, 100-164 are
>   SBAS satellites az    Yes numeric Azimuth, degrees from true north.
>   el    Yes numeric Elevation in degrees. ss    Yes numeric Signal strength in
>   dB. used  Yes boolean Used in current solution?  gnssid   No  numeric The
>   GNSS ID, as defined by u-blox, not NMEA. 0=GPS, 2=Galileo, 3=Beidou,
>   5=QZSS, 6-GLONASS. svid   no  numeric The satellite ID within its
>   constellation. As defined by u-blox, not NMEA. sigid  no  numeric The
>   signal ID of this signal. As defined by u-blox, not NMEA.
>
> Example
>
> {"class":"SKY","device":"/dev/pts/1",
>       "time":"2005-07-08T11:28:07.114Z",
>       "xdop":1.55,"hdop":1.24,"pdop":1.99,
>       "satellites":[
>           {"PRN":23,"el":6,"az":84,"ss":0,"used":false},
>           {"PRN":28,"el":7,"az":160,"ss":0,"used":false},
>           {"PRN":8,"el":66,"az":189,"ss":44,"used":true},
>           {"PRN":29,"el":13,"az":273,"ss":0,"used":false},
>           {"PRN":10,"el":51,"az":304,"ss":29,"used":true},
>           {"PRN":4,"el":15,"az":199,"ss":36,"used":true},
>           {"PRN":2,"el":34,"az":241,"ss":43,"used":true},
>           {"PRN":27,"el":71,"az":76,"ss":43,"used":true}]}

*GST*

> A GST object is a pseudorange noise report.
>
> Name  Always? Type    Description class   Yes string  Fixed: "GST"
>   device    No  string  Name of originating device time No  string  Time/date
>   stamp in ISO8601 format, UTC. May have a fractional part of up to
>   .001sec precision. rms    No  numeric Value of the standard deviation of
>   the range inputs to the navigation process.
>
> Example
>
> {"class":"GST","device":"/dev/ttyUSB0",
>           "time":"2010-12-07T10:23:07.096Z","rms":2.440,
>           "major":1.660,"minor":1.120,"orient":68.989,
>           "lat":1.600,"lon":1.200,"alt":2.520}

*ATT*

> An ATT object is a vehicle-attitude report. It is returned by
>   digital-compass and gyroscope sensors; ...

*Commands*

> ***?VERSION***; Returns an object with the following attributes:
>
> ***?DEVICES***; Returns a device list object with the following elements:
>
> ***?WATCH***; This command sets watcher mode. It also sets or elicits a
>   report of per-subscriber policy and the raw bit. An argument WATCH
>   object changes the subscriber's policy. The response describes the
>   subscriber's policy. The response will also include a DEVICES object.
>
> ***?POLL***; The POLL command requests data from the last-seen fixes on all
>   active GPS devices. Devices must previously have been activated by
>   ?WATCH to be pollable.
>
> The POLL response will contain a timestamped list of TPV objects
>   describing cached data, and a timestamped list of SKY objects
>   describing satellite configuration. If a device has not seen fixes, it
>   will be reported with a mode field of zero.
>
> ***TOFF*** This message is emitted on each cycle and reports the offset
>   between the host's clock time and the GPS time at top of second
>
> ***PPS*** This message is emitted each time the daemon sees a valid PPS
>   (Pulse Per Second) strobe from a device.
>
> ***OSC*** This message reports the status of a GPS-disciplined oscillator
>   (GPSDO).
>
> ***?DEVICE*** This command reports (when followed by ';') the state of a
>   device, or sets (when followed by '=' and a DEVICE object)
>   device-specific control bits, notably the device's speed and serial
>   mode and the native-mode bit. The parameter-setting form will be
>   rejected if more than one client is attached to the channel.

*Appendix S - Shau Kei Wan Testing Site*

[image: shau kei wan test site]

*/ to continue, ...*

Answer (score 1):

I'm having similar problems with the same GPS module. I see many corrupted inbound messages and many garbage characters.

I got improved messages by amending the UART config:

```
stty -F /dev/serial0 cs7
cat /dev/serial0
```

After a few seconds, inbound messages were then good; full NMEA sentences and no more garbage characters.

According to the datasheet, the GPS UART *should* be running cs8. So it is odd that setting it to cs7 helped things. I picked up trying cs7 from an Oracle tutorial on using the same GPS unit; see link [here](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RaspberryPi_GPS/RaspberryPi_GPS.html#summary).

**Edit:**

Found an improved answer to why you were seeing all the bad characters.

The Pi UART is by default set to echo mode. This means GPS data on TX is echoed back to the GPS RX. It caused my GPS unit to get confused and start sending garbage characters, like OP saw.

This presumably reflects Pi UART original purpose of working as a tty console. Echo is required for normal console behaviour.

Fix is simply to reconfigure the Pi UART by disabling the echo.

Worked as expected after I'd configured with:

```
stty -F /dev/serial0 -echo
```

As a useful side effect, the "cs7" workaround was no longer needed & the default "cs8" worked fine.