# Probably GPSD commands not on $PATH. How to put cgps or xgps on $PATH?

Tags: gps

I installed gpsd, get data stream via SSH, but cgps or xgps commands do nothing.
How to ensure GPSD is properly installed and commands are on `$PATH`?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is very cryptic. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: Please explain exactly how you installed GPSD.  Also detail what happens when you try to use these commands. If they are simply not in path, you should get something equivalent to "command not found".  If something else, or nothing, happens, then that is not the problem -- but again more details are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Question***

> Installed gpsd, ... commands do nothing.
>
> How to ensure GPSD properly installed and commands are on $Path?

***Answer***

***Update 2019may28hkt1720***

cgps and xgps run smoothly after installed the 6 packages below.  All $path stuff are already automatically taken care of without newbies noticing anything.

[image: gps_cgps_xgps]

Perhaps you forgot to install some libraries.

This afternoon I happened to also install GPSD.  I am a GUI guy, don't know nothing about terminal commands, not to mention the newbie scary $path.  What I did was click, click, click, and tick, tick, tick, ...

> 1. From GUI Desktop > Install Software > Search "gpsd".
> 2. Tick all the GPSD stuff that looks useful.
> 3. Click OK.
> 4. [Day is done](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzzq7RMh7b0), no tears! :)

[image: gpsd install]

***References***

[Testing GPS Module](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98840/is-my-gps-module-fried)