# How to copy the gps data from Raspberry Pi terminal to a text file?

Tags: raspbian, gps

I'm getting the Gps values after running the following commands in Raspberry Pi .

```
sudo gpsd /dev/ttyACM0 -F /var/run/gpsd.socket

gpsmon
```

How can I copy or write the gps data displayed on terminal to a text file?

Comment: My old answer might help - https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98840/is-my-gps-module-fried

Answer (score 7):

Pipe the output from gpsmon into a file. (if the file exists already and is writable it will be wiped)

```
gpsmon > gpsmon.txt
```

Pipe the output from gpsmon to append to an existing file (provided file permissions allow write access)

```
gpsmon >> gpsmon.txt
```

Use 'tee' command to display on the terminal and pipe to a file at the same time. (same caveats on permissions occur - will overwrite existing file).

```
gpsmon | tee gpsmon.txt
```

Use 'tee' to display on the terminal and append to a file.

```
gpsmon | tee -a gpsmon.txt
```

All examples where 'gpsmon.txt' is the name of the file where your output will be saved. If gpsmon.txt doesn't exist it will be created.