# Will eBay USB GPS Antenna work with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gps

Do you reckon this eBay USB GPS Antenna (https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.co.uk%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F143312562035) will work with a Raspberry Pi and if so will I be to use this tutorial to utilise it: https://youtu.be/A1zmhxcUOxw

All answers appreciated!
Eddie

Comment: Your eBay GPS ad has no model number or spec. 
 I would rather buy from AliExpress or Amazon, with spec and instructions. Your tutorial as a bit too brief. 
 You can find more more references and tutorials from Google or this thread:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98840/is-my-gps-module-fried

Comment: I’ll have a quick check on AliExpress

Comment: Thanks so much! AliExpress is great! See my new answer for more info

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here and note how Stackexchange differs from other online forums.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a look on AliExpress and found this: https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/eICTLDO

On one of the images in the item description it claims it supports Raspberry Pi!
It is a bit more expensive at £4 instead of £3, but with the AliExpress New Customer Voucher it goes down to £1.16!

Thanks everyone, I will buy this one!

Eddie

Comment: Just remember to take care if you buy something for more than £15 from a non-EU country.  You might be hit by customs duty/import VAT in the UK.

Comment: It’s £1.65! Not £15! But I understand! I think it should be ok

Comment: Your purchase will be fine.  It was just a caution for future purchases.

Comment: Great! I’ll make sure I’ll take care of that in the future!

Answer (score 0):

It should work.  GPS units have a pretty basic but standard interface.

I have no idea if the linked tutorial is any good as I couldn't be bothered to sit and watch it.

Comment: It’s fine that you didn’t watch the video! I’ll just buy the thing and see if it works! I mean what’s there to lose? £3!

Comment: That would be my attitude as well.  I know £3 is a lot for some people but if you can afford it then I'd take the small risk of it not working.

Comment: Hi! Turns out on AliExpress I can get one for even cheaper. See my new answer for more info!