# GPS BU-353S4 with Pi4 - not reading position, only timestamp

Tags: raspbian, gps, pi-4

I'm just gonna say real quick that I've through about 20 threads on this topic, so I know this issue has been brought up *many* times, but the problem seems to change for every new build of raspbian or the pi itself, so here I am.

I'm using a raspberry pi4 b+, with a BU353-S4 usb gps, and I've had almost nothing but problems with `gpsd`. I seem to be able to get the current timestamp, but only twice have I been able to measure the latitude and longitude. I didn't make changes to any config txt but the next time I would try to run `gpsd`, I would not get position information.

[image: output]

You can see the output at the top, it is stuck to 180 degrees N and 0 deg E.

My `/etc/default/gpsd` config file looks like this:

```
chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB1

START_DAEMON="true"

USBAUTO="false"

DEVICES="/dev/ttyUSB0","/dev/ttyUSB1"

GPSD_OPTIONS="-n -b -G"
GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"
```

So my question is either are there any alternatives to `gpsd`? Some googling as lead me nowhere as of yet. Otherwise, what could be the issue behind this lack of output?

Comment: But gpsd is the best! :) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98840/is-my-gps-module-fried.

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.