# upload GPS real time data to web browser with wifi

Tags: pi-3b+, arduino, server

i am doing a project for my collage. The objective of this project is to collect real time GPS data and displaying the data on a web server, i am now able to run the program on Arduino IDE to get the lat and long. However, i am now stuck at how to upload the data to a web browser. i am have Adafruit Flora, GPS Module, Raspberry Pi3 B+ and a Arduino UNO Board. please advise, thanks!

[image: Adafruit flora and Adafruit GPS module]

Comment: Well, if you can get GPS data to Arduino, then you don't need Rpi. You can use ESP8266 to wifi your data to a web server.  Though you can do everything in Rpi,  say, using GPSD and python to get data and upload it to any web server.  But the learning curve of Rpi python GPSD is rather steep: (1) Rpi UART to GPS Problem
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98840/rpi-uart-to-gps-module-connection-problem, (2) Apndix O - GPSD Howto
https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/client-howto.html, (3) Apndx R - GPSD Client Library for Python Programming, https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/gpsd_json.html

Comment: Welcome.  *"I am now stuck at how to upload the data to a web browser"* -> You need to do that via a **web server**, which implements the protocol(s) necessary to communicate with a web browser.  It sounds like you have a fair amount of research to do -- but nothing about this is particular to the Pi.  General web programming questions belong on our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: If the focus of your question was actually *"How do I get the information from the Arduino so that I can make it accessible on the Raspberry Pi"* (outside of the Arduino IDE), that is fair question (but the red herring of the web server overshadows that as currently written).  It also depends on how it is connected to the Pi.  USB is implicit here, but you have not made that clear.  In short, if you want your question re-opened, it will need some refinement to focus on concrete details first.