# Need a constant power supply for raspberry pi

Tags: voltage

I'm using a raspberry pi which is connected to a gps. What we do is we plug the raspberry pi to a truck with a car charger so we can track it. But the problem we are facing is that the truck moves around a lot and the raspberry pi losses its power. Currently we are using and adjustable voltage regulator but that keeps moving since the truck is always on the move. We are looking to use an exact 5.3V voltage regulator for the pi.

Is there any advice on what we should to keep the raspberry pi on and not lose its power?

Thanks, 
Muhammad Rehman

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.amazon.com/Makerfocus-Raspberry-2500mAh-Lithium-Battery/dp/B01MQYX4UX) should help you out

Comment: Ah, you can use a 11.1V rechargeable LIPO power bank and then use LM2596 switching regulator to step 11.1V down to 5V for Rpi.  The LM2596 voltage regulator can also be used when in times you remove your GPS module to a place with 220/110AC and stepped down to 12VDC. See Appendix B and F of my answer to the following GPS question: (1)  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98840/rpi-uart-to-gps-module-connection-problem. Have a nice day!

Comment: please explain how the truck motion is causing power loss

Comment: Sounds like you have a wiring issue not a supply issue.

Comment: Since the truck is always moving, the device (raspberry pi) itself is moving alot. I think this may have caused an issue with the connector of voltage regulator.